# Join with fuzzy matching by date in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two data frames that I'd like to join them by the dates

```
df1 <-
  data.frame(
    day = seq(ymd("2020-01-01"), ymd("2020-01-14"), by = "1 day"),
    key = rep(c("green", "blue"), 7),
    value_x = sample(1:100, 14)
  ) %>% 
    as_tibble()

df2 <-
  data.frame(
    day = seq(ymd("2020-01-01"), ymd("2020-01-12"), by = "3 days"),
    key = rep(c("green", "blue"), 2),
    value_y = c(2, 4, 6, 8)
  ) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

I want the output to be like this

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
   day        key   value_x   value_y
   <date>     <fct>   <int>     <int>
 1 2020-01-01 green      91         2
 2 2020-01-02 blue       28        NA
 3 2020-01-03 green      75         2
 4 2020-01-04 blue       14         4
 5 2020-01-05 green       3         2
 6 2020-01-06 blue       27         4
 7 2020-01-07 green      15         6
 8 2020-01-08 blue        7         4
 9 2020-01-09 green       1         6
10 2020-01-10 blue       10         8
11 2020-01-11 green       9         6
12 2020-01-12 blue       76         8
13 2020-01-13 green      31         6
14 2020-01-14 blue       62         8
```

I tried doing this code

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c("day", "key"), all.x = TRUE)
```

I'd like the day in the left table to join to the most recent day in the Y table that has a value. If there is no value, then it should be NA.

Edit --

Not all the dates in df2 will appear in df1 while they do have a common ID. This is an example-

```
df1 

day           id       key  
1 2020-01-08    A    green
2 2020-01-10    A    green
3 2020-02-24    A    blue 
4 2020-03-24    A    green
   
df2 

day            id   value 
1 2020-01-03    A       2
2 2020-01-07    A       4
3 2020-01-22    A       4
4 2020-03-24    A       6   

desired output

day           id       key    value
1 2020-01-08    A    green        4   
2 2020-01-10    A    green        4
3 2020-02-24    A    blue         4
4 2020-03-24    A    green        6
```

Comment: You need to `set.seed()` first when using `sample` or other random functions to make the result reproducible.

Comment: If you're interested in a *data.table* alternative too, this is a 'rolling join' - `setDT(df2)[setDT(df1), on=.(key,day), roll=+Inf]` and you're done.

Comment: Would the data table solution work given the update to the question?

Comment: Can you check the last 2 values in your desired output? I think they should be 6 and 6.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ronak. I believe they should be 4 and 6

Comment: @Cauder - yep, and it will give 4,6 as the last two results - `setDT(df2)[setDT(df1), on=.(id,day), roll=+Inf]`

Comment: I updated the comment to reflect that I'd like to do this with a large dataset

Comment: From the conversation under the accepted answer, I'm opening a new question

Comment: Posted the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63775540/join-with-fuzzy-matching-by-date-in-r-with-a-large-dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After merging, you can `arrange` the data based on `key` and `day` and `fill` with the most recent non-NA value.

```
library(dplyr)

merge(df1, df2, by = c('day', 'key'), all.x = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(key, day) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  tidyr::fill(value_y) %>%
  arrange(day)

#          day   key value_x value_y
#1  2020-01-01 green      40       2
#2  2020-01-02  blue      45      NA
#3  2020-01-03 green      54       2
#4  2020-01-04  blue      11       4
#5  2020-01-05 green      12       2
#6  2020-01-06  blue       7       4
#7  2020-01-07 green      72       6
#8  2020-01-08  blue      76       4
#9  2020-01-09 green      52       6
#10 2020-01-10  blue      32       8
#11 2020-01-11 green      69       6
#12 2020-01-12  blue      10       8
#13 2020-01-13 green      63       6
#14 2020-01-14  blue      84       8
```

---

For the updated data you can use the following :

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'id') %>%
  mutate(diff = day.x - day.y) %>%
  group_by(id, key, day.x) %>%
  filter(diff == min(diff[diff >= 0])) %>%
  arrange(day.x) %>%
  select(day = day.x, id, key, value)

#   day        id    key   value
#  <date>     <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 2020-01-08 A     green     4
#2 2020-01-10 A     green     4
#3 2020-02-24 A     blue      4
#4 2020-03-24 A     green     6
```

Comment: Can I group this by key? I'm wondering if I had more key values and more dates so the most recent non na value might belong to a different key

Comment: Yes, I think it is better to group by `key`. Updated the answer.

Comment: This didn't solve my use case. I'm going to update the description to reflect why. The problem is that this assumes that the dates in df2 all appear in df1

Comment: @Cauder Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Will this break down for datasets that are more than 20M? Wondering if I should switch to data tables instead

Comment: I am not sure if this will break but `data.table` is usually faster.

Comment: Unfortunately this script does not work with the size of my dataset. It causes RStudio to crash out with "unexpected errors." I mentioned it on this thread, would you be open to writing this with data tables? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774476/what-are-helpful-optimizations-in-r-for-big-data-sets

Comment: That's a great suggestion. I'll mark this accept and open a separate question

Comment: Posted the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63775540/join-with-fuzzy-matching-by-date-in-r-with-a-large-dataset